# Setting up Glassfish Datasource issue

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

I spent a good part of my evening setting up a Glassfish 5.0.1 server configuring a JDBC Connection Pool and deploying an application. The issue I keep running into: [Unable to Connect to JDBC Connection Pool from Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651423/unable-to-connect-to-jdbc-connection-pool-from-glassfish) and [GlassFish connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618812/glassfish-connection-pool)

In Glassfish for MySQL everywhere states to use the `Resource Type: javax.sql.DataSource` and `Datasource Classname: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource`

The above never worked no matter where I put the MySQL Connector jar `glassfish/lib` or `domain/domain1/bin/lib`. All times I deleted the pool I had, cleared the cache and restarted the servers.

I ended up switching to `java.sql.Driver` and `Driver Classname: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Question are how do I make the Datasource work?

Also, what is the difference between Driver and Datasource?

**Edit**

Same issue with Payara-5. I am putting the jar in `lib/ext` but the Driver failed in the same way and was resolved with it there.

> Ping Connection Pool failed for MySQLConnPool2. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Please check the server.log for more details.

Comment: A couple of points: [1] In your final sentence don't you mean "Driver" (or perhaps "DriverManager") rather than "Drive"? [2] Please paste the text of the actual error you are getting. You are using Glassfish 5 but the related posts you link to are nearly 5 years old and refer to Glassfish 3.1. It seems unlikely that your error is identical to those.

Comment: Also, have you considered trying [Payara Server 5](https://github.com/payara/Payara) instead of Glassfish 5: _"Payara Server 5 is a **patched, enhanced, and supported application server derived from GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.x**"_. (I fully realize that does not address your problem at all; it's just a possible alternative approach.)

Comment: @skomisa the error is exactly the same as the ones highlighted from those 5 year old ones which I found troubling. In that trouble I researched other option and found Payara which is currently being downloaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [5.0 to 8.0 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html) there is a reference to a change in the package name from com.mysql.jdbc to com.mysql.cj. Looking at mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar, there appears to be an undocumented change in the package for the data source to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.

I have tested using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource in Payara 5 from the admin console, and it works :-)

Comment: This is correct I found this out but never updated this question with an answer. Issue was that Google kept giving me old docs. Looking on MySQL directly shows this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems at glassfish 5.0 with `mysql-connector-8.0.16.jar`. A look in the documentation of glassfish we had to place the `mysql-connector-5.1.47-bin.jar` into the domains/domain1/lib directory. The connector of 8.0 has no `*-bin.jar` file. So I tried to place the `*5.1.47-bin.jar` into the domain1/lib directory. After the restart of my glassfish server, I tried to define a new Connection-Pool for MySQL with a javax.sql.XADataSource and the DataSourceName `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource`. After setting the properties as described in glassfish documentation MySQL Server Database Type 4 Driver I got a successfull ping